# Quantum Computing for Quantitative Finance

Tags: optimization, simulations, quantitative, quantum-finance

It's been a while that quantum computing is looked as the next step in computational science. I somewhat always tought we were decade aways from it's happening but it appears I was wrong: [ibm-quantum-computing-cloud](http://www.theverge.com/2016/5/4/11589656/ibm-quantum-computing-cloud)  (well, I am still not sure this is a large scale quantum computer or an efficient quantum computer replication; **edit:** changed the link; it is a simulator)

Quantum mechanics and quantitative finance were already linked by some powerfull tools (ex. [Random matrix theory (RMT) in finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/522/random-matrix-theory-rmt-in-finance)) or shady reasonments ([Quantum Mechanics and Economics... What](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17604/quantum-mechanics-and-economics-what)) but I did not really considered quantum mechanics as the next step of QF. For a long time papers I could find on the topic were either quantum mechanics oriented (see [Path_integral_formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) and links) or 'poor' in term of quantitative finance (see [Quantum_finance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_finance) and links).

Now, I can find more interesting papers (currently at work, will post the relevant paper later) and I am somewhat convinced that quantum computing could be a huge step ahead in both optimization and simulation and so in  quantitative finance.

I am now looking for some good sources (keep in mind the aim is 3, I don't necessarly need to go trough all quantum mechanics again) on

1. quantum mechanics
2. quantum computing
3. quantum computing applied to  quantitative finance

Comment: I don't see anything useful coming out of QC in next 10 years. There's a lot of hype, but every time I look at their stuff closer there's nothing of utility.

Answer (score 5):

Try **[Quantum for Quants](http://www.quantumforquants.org/)**, which has contributions from people working actively in quantum computing, and some small scale examples solved on the [D-Wave Systems](https://www.dwavesys.com/) Quantum Annealer.

The picture below is from an article on Finding Arbitrage Opportunities using a Quantum Annealer (the link is on the Q4Q main page).  The annealer can solve *certain* graph theory problems very quickly, including those with multiple constraints on traversing the edges, so that calculations with multi-legged instruments are easier to manage.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For #1 and #2 I really enjoyed this Edx course from UC Berkeley:

[Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Computation](https://www.edx.org/course/quantum-mechanics-quantum-computation-uc-berkeleyx-cs-191x)

And for #3 you seem to have the sources already :)

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9576/quantum-computing-in-finance-list-of-articles) list of articles and sources I have been interested in. They concern Monte Carlo method, derivative pricing and TSP.

And [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/quantum-computing-algorithms) is a link to on-line course on basics of a quantum computing. I took the course and I could only recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one application of quantum computing in financial risk management: [Financial Risk Management on a Neutral Atom Quantum Processor](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.03223.pdf)

It was run on a real machine and seems it will outperform standard approach by 2026. It is not specificly a quant finance algo but mostly a general purpose ML algo. Still, it seems interesting in the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a general advancement on the use of quantum computing for ML, that then can be applied in finance. See: [Financial Risk Management on a Neutral Atom Quantum Processor](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.03223). While it is not strictly quantitative finance, it can impact all ML applications in the financial domain.